# RamMap does not show anything on windows 11 64 bit

Tags: memory

I installed the latest version of RamMap on my pc, and when I run it, it just shows an empty tab of RamMap. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: what is your question? ... what is RamMap? ... where did you get it? ... please update your post with the requested info

Answer (score 0):

SysInternals software generally works fine in Windows 11.

Make sure you are downloading from SysIntenals (Microsoft) and not some other source.

Make sure you are using RamMap 1.61 and RamMap64.exe not RamMap64a.exe

[image: RamMap]